# Error while trying to update Raspberry Pi

Tags: camera

While trying to update the Raspberry Pi (for installing the camera!), I get the following error :

```
.
.
Get:212 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ wheezy/main raspi-config all 20130525-1 [9,062 B]
Fetched 223 MB in 1h 15min 17s (49.3 kB/s)
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages …
dpkg: warning: files list file for package ‘libgtk2.0-common’ missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package ‘libxcb-glx0:armhf’ is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you installed `libgtk2.0-common` successfully?

Comment: Yes. I get "libgtk2.0-common is already the newest version." when I do "sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-common"

Comment: What kind of camera are you using?

Comment: I am using the Raspberry Pi camera

Comment: This might get you closer, looks like a pretty similar error although on Ubuntu: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1634994

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am not sure if that would offset some of the dependencies and stuff. Anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: Have you told `raspi-config` that you are using the camera board?

Comment: Reg : raspi-config. The camera option was not available from the menu when I upgraded my Pi! I thought this error was holding it back from completing the upgrade :(

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness : I was not able to fix that version. I used the recent version of the Raspbian image and it worked fine!

Comment: @myaccount_ram Good, if that's the case could you create a self-answer telling that it was resolved with the newest version? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Original Poster resolved this issue by using a newer version of Raspbian, as detailed in [this comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8966/error-while-trying-to-update-raspberry-pi?noredirect=1#comment19984_8966).

This answer is a placeholder to show that the issue is resolved until the OP creates a self-answer and marks it as such.

Comment: @myaccount_ram No problem! Glad your issue was resolved, that's what we want. Also, if you are exceptionally happy with an answer, don't forget to upvote it. You should get more involved in the community. Not only does it help increase the quality of the site, it helps the site get closer to graduation. Also, pop in to the chat from time to time. We always like having company and it is one thing that shows we are a useful, growing community.